# mysql forward engineering error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to build a data base and I get this exact error.
Is there something wrong with this table?

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(4) NOT NULL,
>         PRIMARY KEY (`seminarsID`),
>         INDEX `fk_SEMINARS_ROOMS1_idx` (`R' at line 10

SQL Code:

```
        -- Table `CSY2028_13433571`.`SEMINARS`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CSY2028_13433571`.`SEMINARS` (
          `seminarsID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ROOMS_roomsID` INT NOT NULL,
          `seminarName` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
          `seminarDescription` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
          `date` DATE NOT NULL,
          `time` TIME(4) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`seminarsID`),
          INDEX `fk_SEMINARS_ROOMS1_idx` (`ROOMS_roomsID` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_SEMINARS_ROOMS1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ROOMS_roomsID`)
            REFERENCES `CSY2028_13433571`.`ROOMS` (`roomsID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>       Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>       Nothing to fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIME` does not need a length information. So just use

```
TIME
```

instead of

```
TIME(4)
```

Comment: (not that I know mysql but) the comma after the time column line looks wrong too (and would better explain the error message)

Comment: I see nothing wrong about the comma. And the error message is exactly at the `(4)` which indicates the explanation I gave

Comment: OK. Just seemed odd syntax to me (that the list of columns runs into options like primary keY) but I defer to your expertise!

Comment: It must be something else wrong. I tried with TIME but got the same error

Comment: @Dany, help us out here. Remove, say, the primary key line and see if the error goes away, then the index, constraint etc.

Comment: And you can't have the _same_ error as there's no longer the (4) to complain about, so update your post with the exact new error, please

Comment: After I go to forward engineering, in the "Export MySQL Table Objects", there are 9 total objects, 9 selected but I only have 7 tables.
I checked this and I have an extra 2 objects one of them is "nameOfDatabase.timestamp" and the other is "namOfDatabase.aTableIdon'tHave".
I deleted the second one and now it works.
Are these 2 other objects sopposed to be there or is some kind of an error?

Comment: @Dany: If I execute the script it works if I remove the constraints. If it does not work for you then the tables you refer to are not matching. Check your `rooms` table

Comment: just managed the problem. There where 2 of the tables doubled up.
Thank you all for your time :)